# WSO2 ESB Uri-template how to add optional query parameter

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to add an optional query parameter to API Uri-template.

```
http://myapi.com/v1/staff/{department}?filter=nerds
```

So in this case resource should be possible to be called w/wo parameter

```
http://myapi.com/v1/staff/IT OR http://myapi.com/v1/staff/IT?filter=nerds
```

My current URI-template

```
/staff/{department}*
```

This works but only with parameters. Calling resource without parameters will get no match.  Addition to this wildcard I've tried to use optional query params defined in RFC 6570 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-3.2.8 but I can't even save API with URI
`/staff/{department}{?filter}` should this work ?

Thanks for any help,
Kari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, you can define two resource blocks with different URi_Template pattern

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll go with this workaround. It relatively easy to copy-paste in source view. Hopefully URI-template support gets improved in future.

Answer (score -2):

Try this uri-template
/staff/{department}?*

and access the query parameters like below

```
<log level="full">
               <property name="SYMBOL" expression="$url:filter"/>
            </log>
```

Comment: This will break the existing functionality of accessing `/staff/testingStaff" call (without the query parameters)